# Comparing the permissions(octal) of files with an integer in Bash Shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal, permissions

I'm in a bit of trouble during my shell script.
I have this code until now.

```
echo "Give directory name"
read  dirname;
if [ -d "$dirname" ]; then
    for filename in "$dirname"/*
    echo "Files found: $(find "$dirname" -type f | wc -l)"
    do
        if [ $(stat -f "%a" "$filename") == "$first" ]; then
        echo "Files with ($first) permission is: $filename"
        fi
    done

fi
```

When I run it on the terminal, I can see that my computer asks for access(which means that I have done well until now. 
The whole idea is that I search for files' permission and I compare this permission in the octal system with a given number($first).
In the end, it shows nothing and the script is looping from the start.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What system are you running this on? Different versions of `stat` take their arguments and format differently, and the way you're using it doesn't match any version I know of. Also, to clarify what's going on, try putting `set -x` at the beginning of the script so it'll print what it's doing as it runs. BTW, one possibility is that the shell you're using doesn't allow `==` in a `[ ]` test -- try using `=` for comparison instead.

Comment: I'm using Mac OS and I run the script from my terminal(Using Microsoft Visual code for editing).
I changed the double == with single = and I'm running on the same loop.

Also, I put the set -x and was hundred of results with this:

[code]
+ for filename in '"$dirname"/*'

++ stat -f %a 'Downloads/test.pdf'

++ wc -l

+ '[' 1 == 644 ']'
[code]

Comment: On macOS' version of `stat`, `%a` gets the file's access time, not its permissions. Also, where is that `wc -l`coming from? Do you have an alias defined overriding the normal `stat` command or something?

Comment: wc -l is the code on the 5th line. I added a half-hour ago(I'm sorry). It calculates all the files in the directory.
Do you know what method could I use so I can have access to octal permissions'  files and then compare them with the first integer?

Comment: Try `stat -f "%Lp" "$filename"` -- that's the macOS (/bsd) format to get the permissions in octal. I'd also switch to a single `=` operator (it's standard in a `[ ]` test). And that `find ... | wc -l` is probably not doing what you want -- it'll skip subdirectories themselves, but include the files inside the subdirectories.

Comment: Are you sure there is a line between the "for" and the "do"? I don't think it would work that way.

Comment: Yes. I need to calculate how many files are in the directory with the specific number of permission

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace this script by:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -r -p $'Give directory name:\n' dirname
if [ -d "$dirname" ]
then
    read -r -p $'Give expected octal permissions:\n' first
    mapfile -d '' -t files < <(
      find "$dirname" -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm "$first" -print0
    )
    if [ "${#files[@]}" -gt 0 ]
    then
      printf 'Found: %d files with the (%s) permission in %s:\n' "${#files[@]}" "$first" "$dirname"
      printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
    else
      printf 'Found no file with the (%s) permission in %s\n' "$first" "$dirname"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: I replace it but it doesn't work properly. You know, I have put "read -r first" outside of "If else"
So the integer has inputted from the start of the script. Now I want to compare the integer($first) with the octal permissions of the files in the directory